# Form is not laid out correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms form hosted in VB6 application (I am not sure if this is significant). Sometimes form controls are layouted incorrectly (primarily Anchor property doesn't work). If I just resize a form by mouse - the form is drawn as it should. Is there any method that may solve my layout problems without manual form resizing? I tried PerformLayout, Invalidate and Refresh methods... but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: Could you add more details, and maybe some screenshots ?
Did you add your controls by designer or programmatically ?

Comment: When is the form drawn incorrectly?

Comment: This sounds like a bug either in VS itself, or the compiler. I've had this same problem many times, after ruling everything else out. Are you using VS2008?

Comment: Do you use TableLayoutPanel to manage form layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the form's Layout event to layout the controls the way they should be.